# Clear form on success submit in grails

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

Is there is some way to clear fields after success submit in grails application?

```
<g:formRemote name="songList" url="[controller: 'SongList', action:'create']"
              update="[success: 'updateSongList', failure: 'error']">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="songList">Enter name of song list:</label>
        <g:textField name="title"  class="form-control" id="songList"/>
    </div>
    <g:submitButton name="Create" />
</g:formRemote>
```

or I should write custom code for this? In grails tag g:formRemote there is method onSuccess, but how correct use it in this case don't imagine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this:

```
$('form[name="songList"]')[0].reset()
```

with in your success method: `updateSongList()`

Comment: g:formRemote is deprecated. Better to use seperate ajax tag.

Comment: really? I usually write js code myself . But try using `<g:remoteLink>`  http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html

Comment: Okay, thank you I will try this. Also thanks other guys about information.